# How to tell whether a class/method is accessible using reflection?

Tags: .net, reflection, visibility, reflection.emit

I use a Dynamic Assembly to create derived classes at run time. How can I tell, using reflection, whether the base class and individual methods in the base class can be used/called from within the derived class in the dynamic assembly?

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of properties on the `MethodInfo` and `Type` objects that you can use to query visibility.

For example, for a type you can check `IsPublic`, `IsPrivate`, `IsNotPublic`, `IsNested`, `IsNestedFamOrAssembly`, and a whole lot more.

For a method (the `MethodInfo` object), you've got a similar set: `IsPublic`,`IsPrivate`, `IsFamilyOrAssembly`, etc.

So combine this with information like the `Assembly` property on a type (so you can tell if Type1 and Type2 are both in the same assembly) and you should be able to get all of the information you need.

Comment: If the .NET framework really provides no direct way to answer my question, is there at least a list of rules somewhere? For example, it would be easy to forget that just because a nested class IsPublic doesn't mean it's accessible, not if the parent class is internal.

Comment: Yeah, thats the problem, there are rules, but you would have to build in code to check them yourself.  I'm not even sure of a specific resource that lists what all of the rules are (though I'm sure one exists somewhere).  If I were doing this myself I would probably build something that handles the most common cases, and then add in the others as I come across them.  Kinda depends on who your audience is as well, though.